# Why does this xbox controller monitor program work?

Tags: python, class, controller, python-multithreading

I have the following code but I am not entirely sure about why the ending works.

```py
from inputs import get_gamepad
import threading

class XboxController(object):
    MAX_TRIG_VAL = pow(2, 8)
    MAX_JOY_VAL = pow(2, 15)

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.LeftJoystickY = 0
        self.LeftJoystickX = 0
        self.RightJoystickY = 0
        self.RightJoystickX = 0
        self.LeftTrigger = 0
        self.RightTrigger = 0
        self.LeftBumper = 0
        self.RightBumper = 0
        self.A = 0
        self.X = 0
        self.Y = 0
        self.B = 0
        self.LeftThumb = 0
        self.RightThumb = 0
        self.Back = 0
        self.Start = 0
        self.LeftDPad = 0
        self.RightDPad = 0
        self.UpDPad = 0
        self.DownDPad = 0
        self._monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._monitor_controller, args=())
        self._monitor_thread.daemon = True
        self._monitor_thread.start()

    def read(self): # return the buttons/triggers that you care about in this methode
        x = self.LeftJoystickX
        y = self.LeftJoystickY
        a = self.A
        b = self.X # b=1, x=2
        rb = self.RightBumper
        rt = self.RightTrigger
        return [x, y, a, b, rb, rt]

    def _monitor_controller(self):
        while True:
            events = get_gamepad()
            for event in events:
                if event.code == 'ABS_Y':
                    self.LeftJoystickY = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_X':
                    self.LeftJoystickX = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RY':
                    self.RightJoystickY = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RX':
                    self.RightJoystickX = event.state / XboxController.MAX_JOY_VAL # normalize between -1 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_Z':
                    self.LeftTrigger = event.state / XboxController.MAX_TRIG_VAL # normalize between 0 and 1
                elif event.code == 'ABS_RZ':
                    self.RightTrigger = event.state / XboxController.MAX_TRIG_VAL # normalize between 0 and 1
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TL':
                    self.LeftBumper = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TR':
                    self.RightBumper = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_SOUTH':
                    self.A = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_NORTH':
                    self.Y = event.state #previously switched with X
                elif event.code == 'BTN_WEST':
                    self.X = event.state #previously switched with Y
                elif event.code == 'BTN_EAST':
                    self.B = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_THUMBL':
                    self.LeftThumb = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_THUMBR':
                    self.RightThumb = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_SELECT':
                    self.Back = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_START':
                    self.Start = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY1':
                    self.LeftDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY2':
                    self.RightDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY3':
                    self.UpDPad = event.state
                elif event.code == 'BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY4':
                    self.DownDPad = event.state

if __name__ == "__main__":
    joy = XboxController()
    while True:
       print(joy.read())
```

When I run the code it works perfectly. However I am not sure how this updates in real time. In the if **name** == '**main**' the While loop goes through and prints out the return from the joy.read(). But since joy was defined outside of the while loop, how does the code go back and redefine all the values in joy? Is it due to the threading? I am unsure and sure could use some help understanding this. Thanks!!

I tried to read input from an xbox controller from a code that was already written. The code works but I dont fully understand why.

Comment: *"Is it due to the threading?"* Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Klaus already stated that it is due the Threading

here's a little explanation that might help you from my side,

When `joy` is called in the while loop, Python tries to find the joy variable in Environments (The Python scope concept follows the `LEGB (Local, Enclosing, Global and Built-in)` rule).

`joy` is in the local environment I believe, and when it's found the class `XboxController` is triggered. As the constructor `__init__` is called every time an object is created from a class, your provided code works!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So basically the threading is constantly updating the values in the __init__, and when it loops through joy.read(), it is getting the updated values due to the threading? Based on your response it sounds like a new Controller() object is being created every time joy.read() is being called? I thought it would just update the values in the object itself?

Comment: I think it does update the values instead of creating a new object...